# C: copying struct/array elements

Tags: c, arrays, struct, copy

I have a file in a known format and I want to convert it to a new format, eg.:

```
struct foo {
    char            bar[256];
};

struct old_format {
    char            name[128];
    struct foo      data[16];
};

struct new_format {
    int             nr;
    char            name[128];
    struct foo      data[16];
};

static struct old_format old[10];
static struct new_format new[10];
```

Problem: after filling 'old' with the data I don't know how to copy its content to 'new'. If I do

```
new[0].name = old[0].name;
new[0].data = old[0].data;
```

I get a compile error about assigning char * to char[128] (struct foo * to struct foo[16], respectively).

I tried a solution I found via Google for the string part:

```
strcpy (new[0].name, old[0].name);
new[0].data = old[0].data;
```

but I have no idea how to handle the struct. Seems I lack basic understanding of how to handle arrays but I don't want to learn C - I just need to complete this task.

Comment: Why would I take C classes without wanting to learn C?

Comment: `bar` and `name` aren't (necessarily) zero-terminated strings--they're fixed-length char arrays.  Without more information about what these arrays actually contain, you shouldn't be using strcpy at all.

Comment: They actually are zero-terminated but out of curiosity: if they weren't would I also use memcpy?

Comment: `memcpy` should always work.  And even for zero-terminated strings, `strncpy` might be preferable here if you don't want your program to behave inappropriately if the data, unexpectedly, isn't zero-terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to learn C, you should be able to read the old file format in any language with a half-decent IO library.

To complete what you're trying to do in C, you could use memcpy.

So instead of:

```
new[0].data = old[0].data;
```

Use

```
memcpy(new[0].data, old[0].data, sizeof(foo) * 16);
```

Comment: And I guess that would work independent of the struct members' types (eg. if I have uint32_t from stdint)?

Comment: It actually was

    memcpy(new[0].data, old[0].data, sizeof(struct foo) * 16);

but it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: You could take the constant away by using sizeof(old[0].data) instead of the explicit calculation (sizeof(element)*number_of_elements). That way it won't silently break if the array is extended in size.

Comment: @dribeas - not a concern here, as the old file format is known to use a certain size, so if the array changes size, the program will be incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap the C arrays in a `struct`. Then copying elements will copy the array automatically.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];
} name_array_t;

struct {
    name_array_t name_struct;
    ...
} x;

struct {
    name_array_t name_struct;
    ... other members ...
} y;

x.name_struct = y.name_struct;
```

Answer (score 0):

(too obvious solution may be)

As we are dealing with the array, we can not do this kind of operation

new.name = old.name;

so i suppose you have to write a function

void Function (char *name , struct new_format *new );
where you need to assign charecter one by one.

Obviously you will Call like this   :  Function (old.name , &new)